# Error Sonata Classification Bundle

Tags: php, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I have installed Classification bundle and also install its depends bundle, I have configured all steps from http://sonata-project.org/bundles/classification/master/doc/index.html
But I have faced following error

**PHP Fatal error: Class 'Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle' not found in myproject\app\AppKernel.php in line PHP Stack trace:**

I have also registered this bundle in AppKernal and Application bundle  found in src source directory, can anyone has idea about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to run the following command:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataClassificationBundle
```

This will generate a bundle in your Application folder as it is mentioned in the documentation here: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/classification/master/doc/reference/installation.html